# how to save Current project properties as a property sheet

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using vs 2017 
**summary of the problem** (
I want to save Current project properties in a property sheet .
when I save the sheet after creation nothing saved .
I have to delete any property I want to save ->press ok ->write it again->press ok  to be saved! )

I do this steps :

View->Other Windows -> Property Manager

[View->Other Windows -> Property Manager->add new sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwT9N.jpg)

Creating the sheet (named test)
[test sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtA0B.jpg)

My main project Configuration

[Additional include directories picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2e0N.jpg)
after opening test.props  we can see  Additional include directories same as my main project equal to

```
$(WXWIN)\include\msvc;$(WXWIN)\include
```

I do right click then save test 
But the problem rise here : 
when I load test.props in another project **Additional include directories** become empty  . 
 the only solution I found is to  save every thing manually. 
 by open test.props   then **delete** -> **$(WXWIN)\include\msvc;$(WXWIN)\include**
from **Additional include directories** then ok 
reopen sheet and paste the value again to be saved !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you could try to follow the following steps:

1,Use "View > Other Windows > Property Manager" to bring up the Property Manager.  It will show your projects and configurations.

2,Right click a configuration, and select "Add New Project Property Sheet...".  Name it, and select a location that works for all your projects.

3,Edit its properties. This is very important. Regardless of whether the correct path is displayed when you open the property sheet, you need to re-add it manually. An then right click to save after the modification is complete.

Before manual modification:

[image]

After manual modification, the font is bold:

[image]

4,Right click the configuration or project, and select "Add Existing Property Sheet...". Browse to where you saved the original sheet, and it will be inherited.

For more details,I suggest you could refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019